# Was Anaximander the first who described that the clouds and rain were formed by evaporation of the oceans?

Tags: physics

If so how did he managed to see this as molecules weren't known in his days?

Comment: In the only way that "works": observing and guessing hypothesis.

Comment: For details, see e.g. Charles Kahn, [Anaximander and the Origins of Greek Cosmology](https://books.google.it/books?id=c0z-QbIW84EC&pg=PR7) (1960).